# In React, how can I apply a CSS transition on state change, re-mount, or re-render?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-transitions, reactcsstransitiongroup

Say I have a React functional component with some simple state:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core"

export default function Basket() {
    const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState<number>(0)

    return (
        <div>
            <Count count={itemCount} />
            <button onClick={() => setItemCount(itemCount + 1)}>
              Add One
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

function Count({count}: {count: number}) {
    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <div className={classes.count}>
            {count}
        </div>
    )
}

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    count: {
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        transition: "backgroundColor 2s ease"  // ???
    }
}
```

I want the `Count` component to apply a property whenever the `count` changes and then remove it again; say, turn on `backgroundColor: yellow` for 2 seconds and then gradually fade it over 1 second. What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Note that presumably this could be either triggered by a **state change on the parent** or by a **re-rendering of the child**. Alternatively, I could add the `key` property to `<Count/>` to force a **re-mount of the child**:

```
<Count 
  key={itemCount} 
  count={itemCount} 
/>
```

Any of those would be acceptable; I'm looking for the simplest, cleanest solution, hopefully one that doesn't require additional state and is compatible with [Material-UI styling APIs](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/).

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea.

```
const Component = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // will trigger on component mount

    return () => {
      // will trigger on component umount
    }
  }, [])
}

...

document.getElementById('transition').classList.add('example')
```

You can use useEffect along with useRef containing a reference to the element or directly getting it with document.getElementById and then update the transition class that way in component mount/unmount.  Not sure if it'll work, I haven't tested it myself.